# Regex turn to negative validation

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex that check if there is in the string 8 caracters (letters or numbers) followed by a space a number and a comma:

```
    ^.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,} \d*,.*$
```

The following Regex does not match the following:

```
    Hello 23, abc 2, me 5,
```

But match the following:

```
    My8Chara 12, abc 2,
```

I would like to reverse the Regex. I want the regex match if the string does NOT contain 8 characters followed by a space a number and a comma.

Does anyone knows how to reverse Regex ? I cannot use something like !Regex.IsMatch because I use a generic validator. I must write it in regular expression.

The desired output are :

```
    "" -> match
    "abc 123, def 234," -> match
    "my8chara 123, only5 12" -> does not match -> it contains 8 characters followed by a space a number and a comma
```

Thanks in advance,
Raphaël

Comment: Can you give your desired inputs and outputs ? acceptable and unacceptable inputs ?

Comment: So you want to match absolutely everything except that pattern? You might want to look into [negative lookaraounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use a negative lookahead like this:

```
^(?!.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,} \d*).+$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cZ1gO1).

A negative lookahead has the format `(?! ... )`. If what's inside it matched, then the whole match will fail.

So, if there is `.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,} \d*` matched, the whole match fails.

**EDIT**: If you still want to match sentences with the structure `Hello 23, abc 2, me 5,`, then I would suggest this:

```
^(?!.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,} \d*).*(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+ \d*,)?.*$
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost work ! However, when the string is empty the regex validate it... Do you know why ?

Comment: @Raphaël Is the string really empty or does it contain space characters? The regex will match with at least one character.

Comment: Yes, with an empty string, the regex does not match. However, an empty string does not contain the searched string.

Comment: @Raphaël I think I now get what you mean. Could you try the last regex and tell me? Here's the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM0mP6) (I added parentheses to show that the regex also matches an empty string as you mentioned it in your question).

Comment: Thank you, it is working perfectly. However, such a tortured mind to find what you did. Good job and thank you again! You are my Regex freek Jerry!

Comment: @Raphaël Awesome! And it was no problem. I actually just added your initial regex at the end, changed `{8,}` to `+`, then grouped the whole thing in between `(?: ... )` so that I could add `?` to mean that it was optional. That part was what allows the regex to match empty strings.

Comment: You can drop the ".+$" at the end if you just want the simple negative match:  ^(?!.*<regexp>)  matches exactly "strings not matching <regexp> anywhere".

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{8} \d+,)\w.*$
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/yK5mH2)

To match empty strings too:

```
^(?!.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{8} \d+,).*$
```

Comment: Still not working for an empty string. We get almost the expected result. When the regex will match for empty string, I will be happy :-)

Comment: @Raphaël this regex doesn't match empty strings as it should have a letter at least